# Comparing Date objects not working

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have this JS code from where I want to compare 2 time object:

```
 Meteor.setInterval( function () {
  productDate = Products.findOne({});
    var timeNow = Date();
    var timeCreated = productDate.createdAt 
    var productId = productDate._id;
    productDate = Products.findOne({});
    console.log(timeNow + " time now")
    console.log(timeCreated + " time when created")



        if (timeCreated <= timeNow) {
          console.log("working");
          console.log(productId);
          console.log(this.id);
        Products.update({_id: productId}, {$set: {isItReady: true}})

    }
  }, 5000);
```

My console log output is this:

```
I20150423-18:55:09.950(3)? Thu Apr 23 2015 18:55:09 GMT+0300 (EEST) time now

I20150423-18:55:09.950(3)? Thu Apr 23 2015 18:52:52 GMT+0300 (EEST) time when created
```

These are only the 2 first outputs.

Basically I want to know when timeCreated is less then timeNow and then make something. When I check the 2 variables `timeNow` and `timeCreated` with `typeOf` it returns `Object` for both.

What can be the issue, why I dont reach the console.log after the check if `(timeCreated <= timeNow) {` ?

Comment: And you're sure the database is returning a date object?

Comment: Doesn't matter. The string representation should also work. `I20150423-18:55:09.950(3)? Thu Apr 23 2015 18:55:09 GMT+0300 (EEST)` is > than `I20150423-18:55:09.950(3)? Thu Apr 23 2015 18:52:52 GMT+0300 (EEST)`

try .toString() on the objects

Comment: .toString is working. Strange that object comparison doesn't work..

Comment: Just as a test, can you try `if ((new Date(timeCreated.toString())) <= (new Date(timeNow.toString()))) {` and see if it makes a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timeNow variable is a string not a Date object.

```
timeNow = new Date();  // this is a date object
timeNow = Date();      // this is a string value with current date
```

I am not sure the type of your timeCreated but that would also need to be a Date object or converted for the check.

Comment: this is correct. I did the check and timeNow = new Date(); returns an object which is then comparable with the object coming from my database.